# nwfilter: Generated firewall rules don't make any sense

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I'm trying to configure nwfilter for KVM, but so far I haven't managed
to figure out a working configuration.

Network setup: The dom0 (Debian 7.1, kernel 3.2.46-1, libvirt 0.9.12) is
connected via eth0, part of the external subnet 192.168.17.0/24, and has
an additional subnet 192.168.128.160/28 routed to its main address
192.168.17.125.

The host's subnet is configured as bridge in virsh:

```
<network>
  <name>foo</name>
  <forward dev='eth0' mode='route'>
    <interface dev='eth0'/>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='foo-br0' stp='off' delay='0' />
  <ip address='192.168.128.161' netmask='255.255.255.240'>
  </ip>
</network>
```

The domU is configured to use this bridge (static IP configured in DomU):

```
<interface type='network'>
  <source network='foo'/>
  <target dev='vnet0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <filterref filter='test-eth0'>
    <parameter name='CTRL_IP_LEARNING' value='none'/>
    <parameter name='IP' value='192.168.128.162'/>
  </filterref>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

With an empty filter, connectivity is working fine. Now, if I add the
example ruleset suggested in the documentation (
http://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html#nwfwriteexample ), *incoming*
ICMP works (but not outgoing), and inbound SSH traffic is blocked,
together with outbound DNS.

The linked rules produce the following iptables chains:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
libvirt-host-in  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
libvirt-in  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
libvirt-out  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
libvirt-in-post  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.128.160/28  
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.128.160/28   0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FI-vnet0 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED ctdir ORIGINAL
RETURN     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED ctdir ORIGINAL
RETURN     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED ctdir REPLY
RETURN     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED ctdir REPLY
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FO-vnet0 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED ctdir REPLY
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED ctdir REPLY
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state ESTABLISHED ctdir ORIGINAL
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53 state ESTABLISHED ctdir ORIGINAL
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain HI-vnet0 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED ctdir ORIGINAL
RETURN     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED ctdir ORIGINAL
RETURN     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED ctdir REPLY
RETURN     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED ctdir REPLY
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain libvirt-host-in (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
HI-vnet0   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]  PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vnet0

Chain libvirt-in (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FI-vnet0   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]  PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vnet0

Chain libvirt-in-post (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vnet0

Chain libvirt-out (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FO-vnet0   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]  PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vnet0
```

If I try the second filterset from the second example from the
documentation (
http://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html#nwfwriteexample2nd
), the resulting firewall rules make even less sense.

To quote, what it should do:

> - opens only TCP ports 22 and 80 of a VM's interface
> - allows the VM to send ping traffic from an interface but not let the VM be pinged on the interface
> - allows the VM to do DNS lookups (UDP towards port 53)
> - enable an ftp server (in active mode) to be run inside the VM

What it does:

- Opens all incoming ports
- Allows the VM to be pinged
- Blocks all outgoing traffic (except ICMP, but I suspect that's only because ICMP filtering does not work at all, see above)
- Prevents an ftp server from running in active mode

I have not modified any of the included nwfilter rulesets nor any other part of the network stack. How do I get nwfilter to run properly?